# How do I send a playlist of 16 mp3 files to an orchestra audition panel member?

Tags: email, dropbox, audio

I need to submit an "audition tape" to an orchestra audition panel member over email. I have assembled the 16 or so mp4 files, ready to send. The person will forward the material to other members, or jointly listen to them together with them in a room. They will have to be able to fast forward, skip to next track and pause like any normal player would allow. I also would like to set the playing order.

What would be the smartest way to send these? A few choices come to mind:

- Send as normal email attachments (not great)
- Make a zip file and upload to a file sharing service
- Place the files in a dropbox folder which allows for playing in browser.
- Creating an Owncloud playlist
- Making a SoundCloud set and sharing on a website

I would like something that is fool proof for the receiver and makes it easy and fast to forward to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with Dropbox, if you have enough space there.

It's easy

- To share (Just the link required)
- To upload (Just drop it)
- To play in the browser (just paste the link)
- To Download (just download with the browser)

I have done this many times (with music and other files). Remember, that Dropbox is actually public, thus make sure you are entitled to share your stuff publicly.

If you like, you may even hand-craft a small html file around your files, to present them in an order, in one place.

You could also use a tool like http://quir.li to allow for jumping to specific positions.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of quir.li*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went on to check your cue tool out. Excellent work!

Answer (score 2):

I would create the playlist online (it doesn't really matter where) and share that.

This solves your problems:

1. It's easy to share and forward to other people.
2. While it doesn't guarantee that they'll play the tracks in the right order it makes it harder for them not to.
3. It doesn't send large attachments around with the e-mail.

The only disadvantage is that they have to be connected to the internet to play your tracks. While this is rare nowadays, it could be a problem if someone wants to listen while on the move and they don't have a (good) mobile connection. In that case choose a service that offers the option to download the playlist.